# How to edit/ sort a non-column column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I wrote the script below, and I'm 98% content with the output. However, the unorganized manner/ disorder of the 'Approved' field bugs me. As you can see, I tried to sort the values using `.sort_values()` but was unsuccessful. The output for the written script is below, as is the list of fields in the data frame.

```
df = df.replace({'Citizen': {1: 'Yes', 
                             0: 'No'}})

grp_by_citizen = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Citizen']).agg({i: 'value_counts' for i in ['Approved']}).fillna(0))
grp_by_citizen.rename(columns = {'Approved': 'Count'}, inplace = True)
grp_by_citizen.sort_values(by = 'Approved')
grp_by_citizen
```

[image]

[image]

Do let me know if you need further clarification or insight as to my objective.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reassign the result of `sort_values` or use `inplace=True`. From [`documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

> Returns: DataFrame or None
>       DataFrame with sorted values or None if inplace=True.

```py
grp_by_citizen = grp_by_citizen.sort_values(by = 'Approved')
```

Answer (score 0):

First go with:

```
f = A.columns.values.tolist()
```

To see what is the actual names of your columns are. Then you can try:

```
A.sort_values(by=f[:2])
```

And if you sort by column name keep in mind that 2L is a long int, so just go:

```
A.sort_values(by=[2L])
```

Comment: I gave a shot, but no cigar. It didn't work because 'Approved' isn't a field/ column.